# Access set cookies in response object

Tags: node.js, express

I'm checking and setting a couple of cookies in the middleware before hitting the route. After hitting the route, inside the handler, I'm trying to access the aforementioned set cookies but the response object has no accessor for these set cookies.

```
# similar to req.cookies.cookie_name to access cookies sent by the client
stored_value = res.cookies.cookie_name # this method doesn't exist
```

The response object exposes a getHeader method, using which I attached a simple cookie parser on response.getHeader('Set-Cookie') to the response object.

```
app.use (req, res, next) ->
  #
  # returns a hash of cookie_name: cookie_value, 
  # or cookie_value if cookie_name is sent as an argument
  #  
  res.jit_cookies = (cookie_name) ->
    cookies = {}

    for cookie in this.getHeader('Set-Cookie')
      tokens = cookie.split(';')[0].split('=')
      cookies[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]

    if cookie_name? then cookies[cookie_name] else cookies

  next()
```

So now I can access the cookies I set anywhere I have access to the response object.

```
res.jit_cookies()      # returns a hash of all cookies set
res.jit_cookies('lang') # returns the value of the 'lang' cookie
```

I'm using cookies so that the state of the response is bound to the response object which is later accessed in many places.

Is this okay to do? Are there other (and better) ways to track and access the same information that I'm trying to use cookies for?

Answer (score 0):

There already is a [`cookie-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) middleware that parses cookies for you and puts them in [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.cookies).

As far as accessing the `req` when you only have `res`, you can access `res.req`.

Comment: Yes, but that is to access the cookies sent by the client.
I'm asking about being able to access cookies set in the response by the server after a request comes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a middleware called: "cookieParser"

If you are using Express v3.X:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

instead if you are using 4.X you need to also import it and use it as follows:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Of course, for the second option you need to first install the package:

```
$ npm install cookie-parser
```

In that way you can get access of cookies like:

```
req.cookies // returns an object
req.cookies['yourCookieName']
```

Comment: Yes, but that is to access the cookies sent by the client. I'm asking about being able to access cookies set in the response by the server after a request comes.